# How to edit parameters of modelica model with OMPython or Python CLI interface

Tags: python, command-line-interface, modelica, openmodelica

I want to edit modelica model parameters in Python CLI interface, But don't know how to find the correct method to make it.

Modelica model code :

```
model Syslam_Q5
  HePackage.Components.Hlam hlam(
    UCfile=
        "C:/Users/Pikachu/Docs/i_v2/H50.txt",
         A_HS_mod1 = 0.0786,
         CSize_flag=false,
         A_HS_mod2 = 0.0914,
         A_HS_mod3 = 0.0223,
         A_HS_mod4 = 0.0245)
```

Python code :

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
cmds = [
    'loadFile("HePackage.mo")',   
    #'removeElementModifiers(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, "component", false)',
    'setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, HePackage.Components.Hlam, hlam.UCfile = C:/Users/Pikachu/Docs/i_v2/H100.txt)',
    #'setParameterValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.UCfile, $Code(=C:/Users/Pikachu/Docs/i_v2/H100.txt))',
    'saveModel("example_edit.mo", Example)',
    ]
for cmd in cmds:
    answer = omc.sendExpression(cmd)
    print(cmd, ':', answer)
```

In a folder i have around 10 text files, I want to run the modelica model for all the text files.
How to do that with Python interface.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this package for testing in `HePackage.mo`:

```
package HePackage

package Systems

model Syslam_Q5
  HePackage.Components.Hlam hlam(
    UCfile=
        "C:/Users/Pikachu/Docs/i_v2/H50.txt",
         A_HS_mod1 = 0.0786,
         CSize_flag=false,
         A_HS_mod2 = 0.0914,
         A_HS_mod3 = 0.0223,
         A_HS_mod4 = 0.0245,
         A_HS_mod5 = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
end Syslam_Q5;

end Systems;

package Components
 model Hlam
   parameter String UCfile = "";
   parameter Real A_HS_mod1 = 0.0;
   parameter Real A_HS_mod2 = 0.0;
   parameter Real A_HS_mod3 = 0.0;
   parameter Real A_HS_mod4 = 0.0;
   parameter Boolean CSize_flag = false;
   parameter Real A_HS_mod5[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 end Hlam; 
end Components;

end HePackage;
```

Then using this `setModifiers.mos` script:

```
loadFile("HePackage.mo"); getErrorString();
list(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.UCfile, $Code(="C:/some/other/file.txt")); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS_mod1, $Code(=1.0)); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.CSize_flag, $Code(=true)); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS_mod2, $Code(=2.0)); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS_mod3, $Code(=3.0)); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS_mod4, $Code(=4.0)); getErrorString();
setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS_mod5, $Code(={1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0})); getErrorString();
list(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5); getErrorString();
```

You get via running: `omc setModifiers.mos`:

```
adrpo33@ida-0030 MINGW64 /c/Users/adrpo33/Downloads
# omc setModifiers.mos
true
""
"model Syslam_Q5
  HePackage.Components.Hlam hlam(UCfile = \"C:/Users/Pikachu/Docs/i_v2/H50.txt\", A_HS_mod1 = 0.0786, CSize_flag = false, A_HS_mod2 = 0.0914, A_HS_mod3 = 0.0223, A_HS_mod4 = 0.0245, A_HS_mod5 = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
end Syslam_Q5;"
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
Ok
""
"model Syslam_Q5
  HePackage.Components.Hlam hlam(UCfile = \"C:/some/other/file.txt\", A_HS_mod1 = 1.0, CSize_flag = true, A_HS_mod2 = 2.0, A_HS_mod3 = 3.0, A_HS_mod4 = 4.0, A_HS_mod5 = {1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0});
end Syslam_Q5;"
""
```

I used a .mos script but you can use these commands via OMPython.

I don't know what you need to do, it might be easier to just build another model on the fly at the top level, something like:

```
loadString("
model SomeParameterSet1
  extends HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5(hlam(file=\"some/file\", A_HS_mod1 = 1));
end SomeParameterSet1;");
simulate(SomeParameterSet1);
saveModel("SomeParameterSet1.mo", SomeParameterSet1);
```

Comment: how to run .mos script, If I use omc setModifiers.mos it says 'omc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you are in windows then do %OPENMODELICAHOME%\bin\omc or add %OPENMODELICAHOME%\bin\ to your PATH env variable.

Comment: How to pass multiple values for one variable, let say a modellica (.mo) file contains   
model Syslam_Q5
  HePackage.Components.Hlam hlam( A_HS = {9.0,8.0,7.0,4.0,5.0} )  end Syslam_Q5;                                                                                                                                                                    How to create .mos file for this, setElementModifierValue(HePackage.Systems.Syslam_Q5, hlam.A_HS, Code(={4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0})); getErrorString();

Comment: Note that you need $Code, not Code for the last argument in setElementModifierValue, but yes, you can put in any expression in there after the = sign, including arrays.

Comment: I changed the answer to add an array component and an array modifier.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do this.

### Use set methods

Use `mod.setParameters(["radius=14","c=0.5"])`, see the [user's guide on OMPython](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html#usage-of-setmethods).

### Override variables at simulation

You can also override variables, including parameters with the simulation flags [-override](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-override) and [-overrideFile](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html#simflag-overridefile).

So adding a command to `cmds`

```py
simulate(example_edit, simflags=\"-override=radius=14,c=0.5\")
```

should work.

If you have a lot of parameters to change use a override file:

```
radius=14
c=0.5
```

Comment: With modelica system, you will be not able to save the edited model also you will be not able to plot variables  and you will be not able to get the results in csv format. Modelica system exports output in .mat format. That's why I didn't opt for mod.setParameters method.so is there a way to do it in Omc.sendexpression format.that will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The set methods like `setParameters` won't change the Modelica model in `example_edit.mo`. It is only used fot he simulation. So `saveModel` won't save changed parameters.

Comment: You can add `outputFormat=\"csv\"` to simulate() to get a csv result files, see your question on the forum: https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/3393-export-results-in-csv-using-ompython#p11231